# Dynamic dropdown from other sheet and column (offset/index?)

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have an Excel document containing 2 sheets, 1 import sheet and a data sheet. The dynamic dropdown in Column B of the Import sheet should be dependant on the value chosen in Column A of the import sheet.

However to find the corresponding "Series" I need to match the ID's from the data sheet. (Eicher ID should match the Series Parent ID; Column B and D)

Screenshots down below should explain it better;

I selected Eicher in User Sheet.A3, now I want to retrieve the ID from DataSheet Column B (mmcMake-24046283). With this I need to find all corresponding Series with the same Series Parent ID. So in this case my dropdown should have shown; Series Eicher, Series 2000, Series 3000, Series 300 and Series 400.

[image: User sheet]

[image: Data sheet]

Comment: I see no way to do this properly with a formula unless you re-arrange your data of `Series` and `Series Patent ID` like the following: `mmcMake-24046283` as column headers and the `Series` list below that header. Next column then with next `mmcMake-…` as header and series listed below. Like explained here: [How to make dependent dropdown lists in Excel](https://exceljet.net/dependent-dropdown-lists)

Comment: So the procedure should be: 1) user select a MakesID in Make column; 2) in the Series column should appear a dynamic drowpdown listing all the series which have a Series Parent ID equal to the Series Parent ID of the selected MakesID. Did i got it right?

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey The user selects a make, not the ID itself. The ID can be found by taking the column to the right of this in the second sheet. The makes and ID willbe paired always there, so the make that is in A2, has its ID in B2. Other than that, all you have stated is correct!

Comment: @DennisSeesing Then i guess the MakesID and Makes Label in the data sheet are inverted? Anyway, let's make say it again with your example: you select Eicher and you want to see the dynamic dropdown with all the Series with a Series Parent ID mmcMake-24046283 (as the Makes colum value), which are Series Eicher, Series 2000, series 3000, Series 300, Series 400; not Series 4000, not seriest 500, not series 600, etc... I think i've found a good formula, but it needs the data to stay sorted by Series Parent ID. Is that possible?

Comment: Ye sorry indeed the labels are inverted on A1/B1. My bad... 

The data gets refreshed via a rest call on opening of the sheet and there might be new additions to the data. So cell C3 / D3 might be Series 2100 and mmcMake-24046283. The data comes from a different system and users are able to create new series for certain makes. The columns will remain the same, A = Makes, B = Makes ID, C = Series, D = Series ID. Column A/B Are linked so the same row will always have the make with the matching ID,Rows in Column C/D will always be "linked" as well,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a code to insert the validation. Check the "setting variables" part to make sure every variable is properly set. Sorry for the quite complex variables names, but empty stomach makes hard to synthesize. :D

```
Sub SubDynamicDropdownGenerator()

    'Declarations.
    Dim StrDataSheetName As String
    Dim StrImportSheetName As String
    Dim StrImportColumnMake As String
    Dim StrDataColumns As String
    Dim StrDataColumnSeries As String
    Dim StrDataColumnSeriesParentIDEntire As String
    Dim BytDataColumnMakesIDInternalColumn As Byte
    Dim RngCellWithDropDown As Range

    'Setting variables.
    StrDataSheetName = "Data"                       'Insert here the name of the sheet with data
    StrImportSheetName = "Import"                   'Insert here the name of the sheet with the import (where the range with the dynamic drowpdown is)
    StrImportColumnMake = "A"                       'Insert here the letter of the column where labeled Make (according to your first picture it is A)
    StrDataColumns = "A:E"                          'Insert here the letters of the columns where the data are located in the data sheet (i guess they are A:E)
    StrDataColumnSeries = "C"                       'Insert here the letter of the column where the Series are located in the data sheet (i guess is the C column)
    StrDataColumnSeriesParentIDEntire = "E:E"       'Insert here the address of the column where the Series Parent ID are located in the data sheet (i guess is the E column)
    BytDataColumnMakesIDInternalColumn = 2          'Insert here the internal reference of the MakesID in the data sheet for the VLOOKUP functions (since it's in the second column, i set it to 2)
    Set RngCellWithDropDown = Sheets(StrImportSheetName).Range("B3") 'Insert here the cell on witch you are going to apply the validation dropdown.

    'Setting validation.
    With RngCellWithDropDown.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
             AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
             Operator:=xlBetween, _
             Formula1:="=INDIRECT(""" & StrDataSheetName & "!" & StrDataColumnSeries & """&MATCH(VLOOKUP(" & StrImportColumnMake & RngCellWithDropDown.Row & "," & StrDataSheetName & "!" & StrDataColumns & "," & BytDataColumnMakesIDInternalColumn & ",FALSE)," & StrDataSheetName & "!" & StrDataColumnSeriesParentIDEntire & ",0)&"":" & StrDataColumnSeries & """&COUNTIF(" & StrDataSheetName & "!" & StrDataColumnSeriesParentIDEntire & ",VLOOKUP(" & StrImportColumnMake & RngCellWithDropDown.Row & "," & StrDataSheetName & "!" & StrDataColumns & "," & BytDataColumnMakesIDInternalColumn & ",FALSE))+MATCH(VLOOKUP(" & StrImportColumnMake & RngCellWithDropDown.Row & "," & StrDataSheetName & "!" & StrDataColumns & "," & BytDataColumnMakesIDInternalColumn & ",FALSE)," & StrDataSheetName & "!" & StrDataColumnSeriesParentIDEntire & ",0)-1)"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Like i've said, it should work as long as the data stay sorted by Series Parent ID. Tell me if you need to appy it on multiple cells. I can edit the code accordingly. Also if you need any explanation on the really messy formula, just say please.

Comment: Testing your code currently. Getting an Application-defined or Object-defined error at this moment. All variables should be correctly set though... Going to continu to try and get it working, will get back to you! Thanks in advance though!

Comment: At what row does the error occur? What variable have you changed?

Comment: Renamed the import and data sheets to match your variables. It errors on row 26-29, the .Add Type part... Just to make sure I did not make any mistakes (kinda new to VBA), where would put this sub (eg; on Import sheet, not in seperate module right?)... Sorry for the basic question

Comment: No need to be sorry. I've put it in a "stand-alone" module. Not in the Import sheet code module.

Comment: I understood you've changed your sheets' name to match my variables. I would have suggested to change the variable value. Anyway, did you change the Name or the (Name)? The (Name) is the "object name" of the sheet, while the Name is the "tag name" of the sheet. Basically Name is the name of the sheet visible to the user while using Excel. That's the name i use in the subroutine.

Comment: I've uploaded a small set of the data including your formula in this Excel file which I published to https://filebin.net/co1u7m6sbhrq6e2i . Don't mind the import sheet since I've been trying to figure out your complete formula and where it goes wrong ;)

Comment: Code edited. StrDataColumns had to be A:E, not A:D. Also StrDataColumnSeriesParentIDEntire had to be E:E, not D:D. Does it work now?

Comment: Also might be the case variable BytDataColumnMakesIDInternalColumn should be 5 instead of 2? Cause right now with 2 the code looks for any Series Parent ID equal to the MakesID. With 5 it would look for any Series Parent ID equal to the given Series Parent ID.

Comment: I will check again tomorrow morning! Thanks so much for your help so far! Will follow up, thanks!

Comment: Tried this morning to get it work, still to no avail :( Does it work for you in the sheet I supplied you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211812/discussion-between-evil-blue-monkey-and-dennis-seesing).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Got it to work after dissecting your formula and fiddling around. Thanks for all your work!