# Dependent Drop Down excel

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I am struggling to make multiple dependent drow-down menu in Excel.

---

`Brand | Model`

`Adidas| MM`

`Adidas| TT`

`Nike  | LL`

`Puma  | OO`

---

The first drowdown list will be based on ***Brand*** column.

I would like to make the second drop down list dependent on value in first drowdown list.

For example, if I am selecting "Adidas" in first drop-down list, the second drowdown list will show only "MM" and "TT" values.

Could you suggest how to do it?

Comment: There are plenty of examples online - have you tried looking at any?

Answer (score 0):

I'm acutally solving a similar problem here: [Dynamic dropdown from other sheet and column (offset/index?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61223400/dynamic-dropdown-from-other-sheet-and-column-offset-index/61228592?noredirect=1#comment108347517_61228592)

Let's try it in a simpler way. Let's assume that

1. Brand column is in column A;
2. Model column is in column B;
3. the cell with the first dropdown list is D1

You need to sort it by Brand. The formula you use for the second dropdown list is this:

```
=INDIRECT("B" & MATCH(D1, A:A, 0) & ":B" & MATCH(D1, A:A, 0) + COUNTIF(A:A, D1) - 1)
```

INDIRECT will tell excel to use the string in the brackets as an address.
"B" is the column where models are listed.
MATCH will search column A (brand column) for the first occurence of the selected brand (in D1) and return its row.
":B" is always because B is the model's column.
MATCH will search again for the first row with the desired brand.
COUNTIF will count how many rows contains the given brand.
-1 subtracts 1.